# Can I test dynamic modules without releasing on the Play Store?

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module

I'm hiring someone to write a library for my app and it will be a dynamic module loaded when the user needs that feature. I can't give that contractor access to the Play Store, so I'm trying to figure out how to get them to test the dynamic feature? Is there a way to test this without releasing to the Play Store? I don't mind if it is part of a beta Android Studio as it will take a while to write this near library.

Thanks.

Comment: The title of the duplicate might be confusing, but it still thoroughly covers the topic.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so I'll have to use `com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.testing.FakeAppUpdateManager` and 
`com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager`? That seems to be the part of the answer relevant to what I need?